# Mouse state winapi

Tags: winapi, visual-c++, windows-messages

Is there any way to get mouse state (position, buttons states) using winapi in C++?
I don't want to use windows messages (WM_MOUSEMOVE, WM_LBUTTONDOWN, etc).

Thank you!

Comment: You don't want to use them and etc?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you are looking for [GetCursorInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms648381%28VS.85%29.aspx) and [GetKeyState](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646301%28VS.85%29.aspx). The latter you call with [virtual key codes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd375731%28VS.85%29.aspx) that specify the mouse button of interest.

Answer (score 1):

If you only need cursor position, you can just use [GetCursorPos](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms648390%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)().  Remember that both [GetCursorInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms648389%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)() and GetCursorPos() return screen coordinates.   Use [ScreenToClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd162952.aspx)() to convert to client area offsets.

Although the OP didn't want to use Windows Messages, I just wanted to mention something as a sidenote.
Something I found was that getting the cursor position as part of a message handler (for instance WM_SETCURSOR), most of the literature recommends using [GetMessagePos](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms644938%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)() to retrieve the cursor's position at the time the message was sent.  However, its the position *before* the mouse moved, not after.   So the position returned 'lags' behind a pixel when trying to do mouseover detection over an area.

Comment: I personally try to avoid calling `GetCursorPos` because of a bug on 64 bit Vista (possibly 64 bit XP), under WOW64. When the pointer you pass is in high address space (>2GB) the function fails. This is fixed in Windows 7, but I still prefer `GetCursorInfo` because it works everywhere.

Comment: Excellent observation.  I'm adding this to my notes.   Thats one of those bang-your-head-on-the-keyboard-while-debugging things for sure.