# mouse coordinates in visual-c++ win32 application?

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio, visual-c++

I have created a win32 application in visual-c++ but this programing not printing the mouse coordinates all other events working properly can any one tell me how to get mouse coordinates in visual-c++ win32 application ?

hoping for quick and positive response.

```
// ttt.cpp : Defines the entry point for the application.
//  TO Demonstrate the Mouse Events

#include "windows.h"
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "stdio.h"


LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    int x,y;
    LPCWSTR msgdown = (LPCWSTR)L"Left Mouse Button Down" ;
    LPCWSTR msgup = (LPCWSTR)L"Left Mouse Button UP" ;
    LPCWSTR msgdblclk = (LPCWSTR)L"Left Mouse Button Dbl clk" ;

    LPCWSTR rmsgdown = (LPCWSTR)L"Right Mouse Button Down" ;
    LPCWSTR rmsgup = (LPCWSTR)L"Right Mouse Button UP" ;
    LPCWSTR rmsgdblclk = (LPCWSTR)L"Right Mouse Button Dbl clk" ;

    LPCWSTR rwheel = (LPCWSTR)L"Mousescroll" ;
    //LPCWSTR txtmsg = (LPCWSTR)L"position" ;
    LPCWSTR mouse = (LPCWSTR)L"Mouse" ;
    switch (msg)
    {
        case WM_CLOSE:
        DestroyWindow(hWnd);
        break;

        case WM_DESTROY:
        PostQuitMessage(0);
        break;

        case WM_LBUTTONDOWN:
        MessageBox(hWnd,msgdown,mouse,MB_OK);

        break;

        case WM_LBUTTONUP:
            MessageBox(hWnd,msgup,mouse,MB_OK);
        break;

        case WM_LBUTTONDBLCLK:
        MessageBox(hWnd,msgdblclk,mouse,MB_OK);
        break;      

        case WM_RBUTTONUP:
        MessageBox(hWnd,rmsgup,mouse,MB_OK);
        break;

        case WM_RBUTTONDOWN:
        MessageBox(hWnd,rmsgdown,mouse,MB_OK);
        break;

        case WM_RBUTTONDBLCLK:
        MessageBox(hWnd,rmsgdblclk,mouse,MB_OK);
        break;

        case WM_MOUSEWHEEL:
        MessageBox(hWnd,rwheel,mouse,MB_OK);
        break;


        char text[50];
        POINT p;
        sprintf(text,"Mouse Position: X=%d, Y=%d",p.x,p.y);
        LPCWSTR textmsg = (LPCWSTR)text;
        SetWindowText(hWnd,textmsg);
        break;


        /*POINT pt;
        GetCursorPos(&pt);

        int a = (int)pt.x;
        int b = (int)pt.y;*/
    }
        return DefWindowProc(hWnd, msg, wParam, lParam);
}

int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance,HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,LPSTR lpCmdLine,int nShowCmd)
{
    LPCTSTR className=(LPCTSTR)"Mouse Test";
    WNDCLASSEX wc;

    wc.cbSize =sizeof(WNDCLASSEX);
    wc.style =CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW | CS_DBLCLKS;
    wc.lpfnWndProc =WndProc;
    wc.cbClsExtra =0;
    wc.cbWndExtra = 0;
    wc.hInstance = hInstance;
    wc.hIcon = LoadIcon(NULL,IDI_WINLOGO);
    wc.hCursor = LoadCursor(NULL,IDC_ARROW);
    wc.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH)(COLOR_WINDOW +1);
    wc.lpszMenuName = NULL;
    wc.lpszClassName = className;
    wc.hIconSm = LoadIcon(NULL,IDI_WINLOGO);

    MessageBoxA(NULL,"mouse events","mouse",MB_OK);



    if(!RegisterClassEx(&wc))
    {
        MessageBox(NULL,(LPCWSTR)"Error Registering Class",(LPCWSTR)"Error RegisterClassEx",MB_OK | MB_ICONERROR);
        return 1;
    }

    HWND hwmd = CreateWindowEx(0,className,(LPCWSTR)L"Mouse Test",WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW,CW_USEDEFAULT,CW_USEDEFAULT,400,300,NULL,NULL,hInstance,NULL);
    ShowWindow(hwmd,SW_SHOWDEFAULT);
    UpdateWindow(hwmd);


    if(!hwmd)
    {
        MessageBox(NULL,(LPCWSTR)"Error Creating Window",(LPCWSTR)"Error CreateWindowEx",MB_OK | MB_ICONERROR);
        return 1;
    }

        MSG msg;

    while(GetMessage(&msg,NULL,0,0)>0)
    {
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessage(&msg);
    }

    return (int)msg.wParam;
}
```

Comment: With the code as posted, you will never reach the code that prints the mouse position.  You break before it, always.  Additionally, casting a character buffer to a wide character buffer will not work either.  You either need to use wide characters always, or replace your current code to use TCHAR's.

Comment: can you tell me how to get mouse coordinates then ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I mentioned in the comment, the following code block 1) will never be reached, and 2) will not work even if you make it reachable:

```
case WM_MOUSEWHEEL:
        MessageBox(hWnd,rwheel,mouse,MB_OK);
        break;


        char text[50]; // no case to get you here!
        POINT p;
        sprintf(text,"Mouse Position: X=%d, Y=%d",p.x,p.y);
        LPCWSTR textmsg = (LPCWSTR)text; // will not work!
        SetWindowText(hWnd,textmsg);
        break;
```

Comment: You will likely want to hand the MOUSEMOVE window message and get the cursor position ... and you will still have to address the casting of `char*` to `wchar_t*` that you currently have (and will not work as you expect it to).

Answer (score 2):

Specifically in WM_MOUSEWHEEL message, the cursor coordinates are passed in lParam. `LOWORD(lParam)` would be x, `HIWORD(lParam)` would be y. Coordinates are relative to the screen, not to your window. Use ScreenToClient() to convert.

The meaning of lParam in WM_xBUTTONDOWN/UP and WM_MOUSEMOVE is the same, but the coordinates are relative to the client area of your window.

Answer (score 1):

Use [GetCursorInfo()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms648389(v=vs.85).aspx) to get the location of the mouse at any point in time.   If you want to track only when the mouse actually moves, handle `WM_MOUSEMOVE`.

[See this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4758527/mouse-state-winapi) previous question/answer for more information.

And as others have said, you'll need to fix your Unicode/char * issues with your strings.